# passwordstore: move entry

Tags: password-store

I'm using the [passwordstore](https://passwordstore.org) to manage my passwords. I've set it up with git. Now I have the use case that I want to rename an entry from 'ABC' to 'abc'. I tried doing it with `pass git mv ABC.gpg abc.gpg`. That worked but there was no commit in my Repository, it is just in the staging area. Should I just commit the change or is there something wrong with my workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may issue the commit with

```
pass git commit
```

`pass` does not automatically commit changes that you make using `pass git`, so you need to commit these separately.

Note that `pass` also allows you to rename entries using

```
pass mv oldname newname
```

This commits the move but first also re-encrypts the moved entry.

From the `pass` manual:

> `mv [ --force, -f ] old-path new-path`
>
> Renames the password or directory named `old-path` to `new-path`.
>                 This command is alternatively named `rename`. If `--force` is
>                 specified, silently overwrite `new-path` if it exists. If `new-path`
>                 ends in a trailing `/`, it is always treated as a directory.
>                 Passwords are selectively reencrypted to the corresponding keys
>                 of their new destination.